# Файлы Sitemap.xml в robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, sitemap, google-search

На сайте интернет-магазина генерируется около 100 файлов sitemap.xml
также генерируется файл siteindex.xml где указаны все ссылки на sitemap.xml

Как правильно указать это в файле robots.txt? Каждый файл sitemap или только siteindex?
И нужно ли заливать файлы sitemap в Search Console? Или их поисковик сам увидит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете описание структуры сайта с помощью файла Sitemap, укажите путь к файлу в качестве параметра директивы sitemap (если файлов несколько, укажите все, если siteindex содержит ссылки на другие файлы, то подключайте только его, чтобы не менять robots.txt каждый раз при изменении структуры сайта). Пример:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Allow: /
sitemap: https://example.com/site_structure/my_sitemaps1.xml
sitemap: https://example.com/site_structure/my_sitemaps2.xml
```

Директива является межсекционной, поэтому будет использоваться роботом вне зависимости от места в файле robots.txt, где она указана.

Робот запомнит путь к файлу, обработает данные и будет использовать результаты при последующем формировании сессий загрузки.

https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html#sitemap

Поисковики конечно же и сами найдут sitemap в вашем robots.txt, но и добавить их самостоятельно в разделах для вебмастеров у поисковиков будет не лишним.